# Selecting options in dropdown Selenium ChromeDriver in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select the options of a dropdown list in Chrome using VBA and Selenium.

I manage to open the dropdown but not navigate the options. Can anyone help?

This is the VBA code:

```
  Sub FormChrome()
   'Import Selenium Library
   Dim driver As New ChromeDriver




'Navigate to the website
    driver.Get "https://fremtindservice.no/privat/bompengekalkulator/"

' Wait for page to load
 driver.Wait (10)
 driver.Window.Maximize
' Locate the first input element using its class and set its value
driver.FindElementByCss("label[for='origin'] ~ div .pac-target-input").SendKeys "Oslo"

' Locate the second input element using its class and set its value
driver.FindElementByCss("label[for='destination'] ~ div .pac-target-input").SendKeys "Rakkestad"
 driver.FindElementByCss("label[for='via'] ~ div .pac-target-input").SendKeys ""

   'driver.FindElementByCss("div.dropdown.v-select.toll-road-calculator__vehicle-type.single.searchable").Click


' Import Selenium Library

' Wait for page to load
driver.Wait (10)

' Locate the dropdown element using its class and click to open it
driver.FindElementByCss("div.dropdown.v-select.toll-road-calculator__vehicle-type.single.searchable").Click
 ' Wait for page to load
 driver.Wait (10)


' Locate the desired option using its position in the dropdown and click to select it
 driver.FindElementByCss("div.vs__dropdown-menu div.vs__dropdown-item:nth-child(3)").Click


End Sub
```

Here is the HTML code for the Dropdown:

Biltype
                     
                            
                                    Personbil
                                
                           ×  Loading...

As a default it says Personbil. I want that text to be the third option in the dropdownlist which is "Lastebil 3.5 tonn (Euro V og eldre)"

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Visual Basic or .net C# ? As far as I know, there is not VB bindings of Selenium.
Re anser, there is special function for select list(dropbox). For #:

```
yourSelectList=driver.FindElement(By.Id("select-demo"));
SelectElement dropDown = new SelectElement(yourSelectList);
```

and then you have 3 alternative to choose options:

```
dropDown.SelectByText("Four");
dropDown.SelectByValue("two");
dropDown.SelectByIndex(3);
```

for more details you can [click here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/)

Comment: I use visual basics.